# How do you correctly insert a Firebase variable?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am a newcomer to Firebase.  I am trying to create a boolean variable.  I would like to define a boolean variable through this expression

```
isEditor(uid) => boolean isEditor
```

If I insert it after:

```
 match /users/{user} {
  allow read, update : if request.auth.uid == user;
   match /tokens/{token}{
    allow write : if request.auth.uid == user;
    }
  }
```

I get a red bar which has an error "Unexpected 'IsEditor'.

The variable seems to be valid in the rest of the code as I get no errors when I use it.

My question is how do I insert the variable in my code so that I do not get the "Unexpected" error?

Comment: The question is a bit vague - what are you trying to do? Are you trying to write a rule for your Firestore? If so, what is the rule supposed to do? If not, can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: There are a number of very long commands in the program.  For instance, the code fragment (request.auth.uid))).data.isEditor is used often.  I would like to replace it by a Boolean variable.  The code fragment is used in the rules.

Comment: The commands in your program are unrelated to [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules)

Comment: I want to create this variable
      isEditor == (request.auth.uid))).data.isEditor
and use it like 


  allow update: if teamID == team && isEditor == true;

Comment: That's not how rules work. Please review the documentation link in my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

The Unexpected error is because you are trying to add a variable of type boolean into Firebase rules, in the rules section you only need to add conditions for your read/writes operations.

I would suggest you to read this documentation first if you want to send data to Firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data